The variance of the resulting Gaussian is found by taking the second derivative of the exponent?
I was reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.18103 about diffusion models.
This is how the author derive the joint distribution  $q\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0\right)$ (at page 22):
Using the Bayes theorem, $q\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0\right)$ can be determined if we evaluate the following product of Gaussians
$$
q\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0\right)=\frac{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \sqrt{\alpha_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1},\left(1-\alpha_t\right) \mathbf{I}\right) \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \sqrt{\overline{\alpha_{t-1}}},\left(1-\overline{\left.\left.\alpha_{t-1} \mathbf{I}\right)\right)}\right.\right.}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x}_t \mid \sqrt{\overline{\alpha_t}} \mathbf{x}_0,\left(1-\overline{\alpha_t}\right) \mathbf{I}\right)} .
$$
For simplicity we will treat the vectors are scalars. Then the above product of Gaussians will become
$$
q\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} \mid \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0\right) \propto \exp \left\{\frac{\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\sqrt{\alpha_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1}\right)^2}{2\left(1-\alpha_t\right)}+\frac{\left(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}-\sqrt{\alpha_{t-1}} z\right)^2}{2\left(1-\overline{\alpha_{t-1}}\right)}-\frac{\left(\mathbf{x}_t-\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_0\right)^2}{2\left(1-\overline{\alpha_t}\right)}\right\} .
$$
We consider the following mapping:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
x=\mathbf{x}_t, & a=\alpha_t \\
y=\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, & b=\bar{\alpha}_{t-1} \\
z=\mathbf{x}_0, & c=\bar{\alpha}_t .
\end{array}
$$
Consider a quadratic function
$$
f(y)=\frac{(x-\sqrt{a} y)^2}{2(1-a)}+\frac{(y-\sqrt{b} z)^2}{2(1-b)}-\frac{(x-\sqrt{c} z)^2}{2(1-c)} .
$$
We know that no matter how we rearrange the terms, the resulting function remains a quadratic equation. The minimizer of $f(y)$ is the mean of the resulting Gaussian. So, we can calculate the derivative of $f$ and show that
$$
f^{\prime}(y)=\frac{1-a b}{(1-a)(1-b)} y-\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{1-a} x+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{1-b} z\right) .
$$
Setting $f^{\prime}(y)=0$ yields
$$
y=\frac{(1-b) \sqrt{a}}{1-a b} x+\frac{(1-a) \sqrt{b}}{1-a b} z .
$$
We note that $a b=\alpha_t \bar{\alpha}_{t-1}=\bar{\alpha}_t$. So,
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu}_q\left(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0\right)=\frac{\left(1-\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}\right) \sqrt{\alpha_t}}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_t+\frac{\left(1-\alpha_t\right) \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}}}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_0 .
$$
Similarly, for the variance, we can check the curvature $f^{\prime \prime}(y)$. We can easily show that
$$
f^{\prime \prime}(y)=\frac{1-a b}{(1-a)(1-b)}=\frac{1-\bar{\alpha}_t}{\left(1-\alpha_t\right)\left(1-\sqrt{\overline{\alpha_{t-1}}}\right)} .
$$
Taking the reciprocal will give us
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_q(t)=\frac{\left(1-\alpha_t\right)\left(1-\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}}\right)}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{I} .
$$
Can anyone give the intuition about why the variance is calculated by taking the reciprocal of the curvature please?

I've read the paper recently and wondered the same thing. The Cramér–Rao bound (see this and this) states that the variance of an unbiased estimator cannot be lower than the inverse Fisher information, i.e. negative expected value of the Hessian matrix (in this case simply a second derivative of the log likelihood function), which gives them the so-called asymptotic covariance matrix (under certain assumptions, the distribution of MLE-estimated parameters $\hat{\Theta}$ is asymptotically normal). So, $x_{t-1}$ is treated as if it lives in the parameter space, which makes sense given the nature of the diffusion model's forward path - all $x_i$, together with variance and scaling parameter $\alpha$ (chosen to ensure the convergence to white noise at $x_{T}$) parametrize normal distributions.
